# Gambit Scheme: gsi and gsc windows closes after end!

Tags: scheme

I'm experimenting with Gambit scheme and I have problem! My OS is Windows 7.
When I try to interpret script I do:
gsi.exe myscript.scm

This works, but GSI's console window is shown and closed just after script finished. I can't see results my program prints! I may do (read-line) at the end, but... when I try to compile with GSC.exe the behaviour is the same: it opens console window, does something, prints about errors and closes it immediately - I can't read something! In this case I can't even do (read-line) hack, you see. How can I view what Gambit writes?

This doesn't works, though:
gsc.exe 1.scm > 1.txt

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file with the commands.  <strike>Set the properties on the batch file such that the window doesn't close after executing(right click, properties on the batch file's icon).</strike>

You can always, add "pause" at the end of the bath file, to keep the window open.

Alternatively, just open a DOSBOX box, and run the script from there.  The box will remain open when the scrip completes.

### UPDATE

**terminal**

To open a terminal(Command Prompt, DOS Box,etc.) use the [Start] button. Enter `cmd` in the "Run" field.
This will open a terminal with a command line interpreter.  You can run *gsc* or *gsi* from there.

**batch files**

Here is the sample program hello.scm:

```
(display "HELLO WORLD")
(newline)
```

Method 1--using *pause*. This example is only for calling binary executable(.EXE) files such as gsc, or gsi.exe:

```
@echo off
gsi hello.scm
pause
```

Method 2--using `cmd /k`. The *pause method* (above) is preferred as this starts another cmd shell:

```
@echo off
cmd /k gsi hello.scm
```

**properties**

Sorry, setting the "Close on exit" property of a command   apparently only exists for true DOS commands via .pif files.

To the same end right-click hello.scm,  then associate it with `cmd /k gsi hello.scm`.

Any of the above batch files may be modified to take a filename argument (as %1, or %* for all args) and run `gsc %1` instead of gsc hello.scm.  After making the batch file generic in this way, associate the .SCM extension with it.

Associate .SCM with run-gsi.bat:

```
@echo off
gsi %*
pause
```

Comment: "pause" in bat doesn't work. Can't find any property related to console window closing.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you had a new comment. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Gambit in an existing terminal window.  Open up your terminal *first*, and then run Gambit.  When Gambit terminates, your terminal will be still up.

Comment: cmd.exe not a terminal window?